# Inner Join for specific data

Tags: sql

my teacher gave us a task which I am unable to solve. I'm not even sure if Inner join is correct but here is the question:

Formulate an SQL query so that the following records are returned for the student Clayton Hughes: all exams for which he has registered, specifically: exam number, exam name, date, examiner, and time of registration.

The other task is:

Formulate an SQL query so that the data of the students who have registered for Biology are returned, specifically: matriculation number, name, birthday.

For both tasks we are not allowed to do specific requests like:
"Student.Matriculation = 1925798"

However "Student.Matriculation" is allowed.

[Tables here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ8b0.jpg)

I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Homework, nice. If you run into problems, you can ask a specific question here.

Comment: BTW, most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know that.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Not good to paste your assignment here, first try it by yourself and then ask a specific question

Comment: I see, though I am still unsure if inner join is correct since I didn't find anything in regards to specific data but rather general table joins.

even w3school:

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S/O.  As others have commented, you should show your attempts before asking the question, or at least edit your original post (in the future) to show the query you have attempted.  So you are going to school for this and apparently not getting the context.  Lets start with what the teacher wants and build out.

Students who have registered for Biology.  In its shortest, you need to find the Biology which is in the Exams table.

```
Select
      e.Name
   from
      exams e
   where
      e.Name = 'Biology'
```

That part makes sense, right?  We have the right class.  So now, you need to see all the people who signed up for that class which is the registration table, correct?  So now, lets join to that to get those registrations.  From the registration table, we can get the matriculated person's ID who signed up, but not their name -- yet

```
Select
      e.Name,
      r.matriculation
   from
      exams e
         JOIN registration r
            on e.exam_number = r.exam_number
   where
      e.Name = 'Biology'
```

One more to go.  Now, we need the student's name who took the class, and since we now have the matriculation id value, we can join yet again.

```
Select
      e.name className,
      r.matriculation,
      s.name StudentName
   from
      exams e
         JOIN registration r
            on e.exam_number = r.exam_number
            JOIN students s
               on r.matriculation = s.matriculation
   where
      e.Name = 'Biology'
```

Notice that as I added each piece with a JOIN, I indented to show how the left-table is associated with the right table.  Additionally, I keep the ON clause to show the left-table/alias column as matched to the right-table/alias column.  In this case, two indentation levels.  Students never directly associates to the exams table.

So, now that you have MOST of the solution, you can now finish by picking all the other fields that your requirements call for.  Try to think of queries in this fashion.  Looking at  the tables, how does A get to B get to C get to D.  This becomes the from clause with your joining on each respective key from each table.

Using aliases (as I have here with "e", "r" and "s") is a shortcut vs typing the long name of the table repeatedly, yet you still have context of the origin "s" from "Students" for example.

I know this is one example of what is askes (such as the query for Clayton), but take it a piece at a time.  Keep building once you get one component at a time.  Start with the first table with the WHERE clause you are looking for, then join after that to the rest.  Keep the chain of relationships and you should be good.